# ASP.net WebApi Multiple controller types were found that match the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have added a new HttpPost route "api/export/error/" to my WebApi, using Attribute Routing, and I am getting an error:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.\r\n\r\nThe request has found the following matching controller types: \r\nMyApp.Controllers.ExportErrorController\r\nMyApp.Controllers.ExportGeneratorController

But I do not have the same routes in different controllers that i see; here are the only routes in those two controllers:

**ExportErrorController.cs**

`[HttpGet]
[Route( "api/export/error/total/" )]`

`[HttpGet]
[Route( "api/export/error/channel/{channelId}/" )]`

`[HttpPost]
[Route( "api/export/error/" )]`

`[HttpDelete]
[Route( "api/export/error/{id}/" )]`

`[HttpPut]
[Route( "api/export/error/clear/" )]`

**ExportGeneratorController.cs**

`[HttpGet]
[Route( "api/2/export/{channelId}/" )]`

`[HttpPost]
[Route( "api/2/export/generate-word/{debugInfo}/" )]`

`[HttpPost]
[Route( "api/2/export/generate-excel/{debugInfo}/" )]`

I cannot see any places that have the same between the two controllers

Answer (score 4):

Apparently ASP.Net does not evaluate parameter 'types' OR methods when determining the route to use so it found and matched the route text "error" as a potential parameter for 'channelid' even though they were different methods.

Adding a type to the parameter helped it resolve it properly so:
`[Route( "api/2/export/{channelId}/" )]`

Is fixed by changing it to:
`[Route( "api/2/export/{channelId:int}/" )]`